# PHP Won't Echo out anything with $_POST

Tags: php, html, forms

I have 2 files, index.html, and welcome.php.

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the PHP:

```
<html>
    <body>
    
    Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
    Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Echo seems to work whenever i'm not using $_POST, with just regular text or variables. Is there something I'm doing wrong? I am also writing this code on repl.it, could that have something to do with it? Major newbie here.

Comment: Just in case, hit Ctrl+U in your browser to inspect the actual raw output.

Comment: it'll only work if you go there directly from submitting the form. I'm assuming that's how you're testing it? if so, then follow Alvaro's suggestion above and check what is actually being output (if anything). The code looks like it should work.

Comment: Put `var_dump($_POST)` (needs to be inside php tags) at the top of your _submit_ page and show the output in your question. `echo` doesn't output certain values...

Comment: If you directly visit `welcome.php`, it won't work (because the form isn't submitted). Other than that potential case, I don't see why the code you presented would fail.

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message you are facing and a way to reproduce the problem